# When clipstobounds = NO extra separators appear below the bounds of UITableview

Tags: xcode, ios6

I apologize in advance if this has been asked before but I cannot seem to find a satisfactory answer. I have a plain UITableview in the middle of a UIView. It is way smaller than the view and so I added a shadow to the table using this code:

```
tableView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
tableView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6;
tableView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
tableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,3);
tableView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
tableView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

The clipsToBounds seems to be the magic setting that puts the shadow in. Unfortunately, it also has the magic effect of drawing separator lines under, and outside, the bounds of my UITableview.

If I add an empty footer, then the separators outside the table disappear, but they also disappear from the table in the cells that have no data. I really want to keep the separator lines even when the table is empty to have a "ruled pad" effect. I am thinking this should be a simple setting but just have not turned it up in my research. Any insight will be greatly appreciated.